# AngularJS directive to format model value for display but hold actual value in model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

In angularjs I am trying to build a directive for currency textbox which takes values (amount and currency code) from the model in scope and then apply currency formatting to it. I am really having hard build the directive using ngModelController's parsers and formatters.

The parser is called first but the modelValue is undefined which means that data has not been returned from the server yet. So how do I make sure that parser is called when model is populated? Similarly my calculation also depends on currency code from db so how do I use these two values in parser?

I am unclear how the render function would look like in my case.

Here is the html:

```
<numericbox caption="RecurringAmount" controltype="currency" currencycode="{{Model.CurrencyCode}}" value="{{Model.RecurringAmount}}" />
```

Here is the directive:

```
export class NumericTextbox
    {
        constructor ()
        {
        var directive: ng.IDirective = {};
        directive.restrict = "E";
        directive.require = '^ngModel';
        directive.replace = true;
        directive.template = '<input type="text" />';
        directive.scope = true;

        directive.link = function ($scope: any, element: JQuerySE, attributes: any, ngModel: ng.INgModelController) {

            var injector = angular.element(document.getElementById('app')).injector();

            var currencyCacheService: CurrenciesCacheService;
            currencyCacheService = injector.get('currenciesCacheService');

            var currency = new Currency();
            var currencySymbol: string;

            ngModel.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {

                if (modelValue) {
                    var amount: number = modelValue || 0;
                    var currencyCode: string = attributes.currency || "";

                    if (currencyCode) {
                        currency = currencyCacheService.GetItem(currencyCode);
                        currencySymbol = currency.CurrencySymbol || currency.ISOCurrencyCode;

                        var formattedNumber = accounting.formatMoney(modelValue,
                            currencySymbol,
                            currency.NumberDecimalDigits,
                            currency.CurrencyGroupSeparator,
                            currency.CurrencyDecimalSeparator);

                        return formattedNumber;
                    }

                    return modelValue;
                }

                return 0;
            });

            ngModel.$parsers.push(function (viewValue: string) {
                if (attributes.currenycode) {
                    var num = viewValue.substring(attributes.currenycode.len, viewValue.length - attributes.currenycode.len);
                    return num;
                }

                return viewValue;
            });

            $scope.$watch(function () {
                var amount: any = {};
                amount.currencycode = attributes.currencycode;
                amount.value = attributes.value;
                return amount;
            }, function (newVal, oldVal, scope) {
                debugger;
                    if (newVal != oldVal) {
                        var amount: number = newVal.value || 0;
                        var currencyCode: string = newVal.currencycode || "";

                        ngModel.$setViewValue({ num: amount, curr: currencyCode });
                    }
            });

            ngModel.$render = function () {
                //$scope.value =
                console.log(ngModel.$viewValue);
            };
        }    
            return directive;
        }
    }
```

The code is in typescript.

Comment: I think you actually want the `$formatter` to get called when the data is returned from the server, since the pipeline is `$modelValue -> $formatters -> $viewValue`. I have the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436691/trigger-ng-model-formatters-to-run-programatically

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the way a value is "displayed" then you need to think in terms of a filter and not a directive. Like this:

```
<div>model.amount|currencyFilter</div>
```

Comment: then STILL use a filter as you are modifying dynamic "presentation" data. You new filter would look like `model.amount|myCurrencyFilter:"DYNAMIC_FMT_FROM_MODEL"`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "DYNAMIC_FMT_FROM_MODEL", that is a static. Do you have an example showing the needed syntax where the filter is variable? What I ended up doing was creating a new filter, just call it customFilter, with a parameter that is the format variable in the scope and in the filter logic using return $filter('date')(item) or return $filter('currency')(item) depending on the value of the parameter (i.e. format, in {{value | custom:format}} ). Originally I wanted to switch from {{value | date}} to {{value | currency}} in the html dynamically based on the scope.format.