# Trigger ng-model.$formatters to run programmatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I'd like a custom control that uses [`ngModel.$formatters`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) to be able to format data as soon as a server dependency loads in. In my case, it needs to load a lookup table to go from one kind of id to another. `$modelValue` stores one thing `$viewValue` displays another. Pretty straight-forward stuff.

The trick is that if my lookup table isn't loaded, I can't do the formatting into a $viewValue.

Once my data loads, I need to do the following:

- `ngModel.$formatters.push(myFormatter)`
- Tell ngModel to start the pipeline from `$modelValue -> $formatters -> $viewValue`

`$render()` doesn't work, this just moves the value from `$viewValue` into the UI control.
`$rollbackViewValue()` looks promising, but that's only in an unstable version ([1.3.0-beta.18](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)).

Code Sample:

```
mappingTable.load().then(function(data){
  mappingData = data;
  ngModel.$formatters.push(myFormatter); // needs mappingData in order to function
  // TODO: Tell ngModel to run the existing $modelValue through $formatters to calculate a  new $viewValue and $render it
  //ngModel.$render() // doesn't work, only puts the $viewValue in the DOM element.
});
```

Comment: Bizarrely, I can set `ngModel.$modelValue = 'foo'` (literally foo) after the data loads. This causes the pipeline to go, but against the previous model value. At the end of this, the modelValue is what I want, the viewValue is the parsed version I want, and 'foo' is nowhere to be found. Works perfectly, but I don't trust it/understand it.

Comment: Try calling `$scope.$apply()`, that will trigger new $digest loop which should use the updated $formatters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the code for ngModelController, it appears that what you stumbled upon (setting `$modelValue` to anything other than the current actual model value) is the accepted way to do this. As you say, the value you set is not used: it just triggers the update. Check its current value first to make sure it actually changes (or use a very unlikely value).

```
if (ngModel.$modelValue == 'bar')
    ngModel.$modelValue = 'foo';
else
    ngModel.$modelValue = 'bar';
```

Here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995414/have-formatters-be-called-when-view-is-first-populated).

Also, there is an [active pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/10764) that looks like an "official" way of doing this is forthcoming.

The reason it works is that ngModelController sets up a `$watch` that runs every digest cycle that compares `$modelValue` to the value that ng-model is bound to.  If they don't match, it triggers the `$formatters` pipeline.